# Interface Builder: back button in navigation

Tags: ios, interface-builder, swift2

Currently I have the below situation in Interface Builder. I want to tap the "highscores" button in Start View Controller. I have tried dragging and dropping a `Tab bar view controller`, I have also tried dragging and dropping a `navigation controller` with `tab bar view controller` as its `root view controller`.

But there is no way I am getting the 'automatic' Back button in the navigation bar, which should link back to the Start View Controller.
What is the best solution?

[image: Current IB situation]

Comment: What kind of transition are you using? You should push the new viewController on the UINavigationController

Comment: It looks like he is using a push transition. Have you tried running the app? The back button won't show up on the storyboard but should appear when you run it.

Comment: It doesn't appear when running it, and indeed, it is a push segue.

Comment: @Jeremiah I'm sorry to poke you, but have you got any idea?

Comment: Is there any code you have that is overriding it possibly? Things that would hide it would be setting leftBarButtonItem to nil or setting the image incorrectly. Also doing anything like adding a navigation bar or something weird in PrepareForSegue could cause issues.

Comment: Ah, so stupid of me, I did override it. I'm sorry :D

Answer (score 0):

These are two questions at once.

First question: **How to show 'Highscores' in a `UITabBarController`?**

According to Apples Guidelines, you should not use a UITabBarController inside of a UINavigationController. But if you really want to add a UITabBarController, don't drag and drop it to your storyboard, but instead select e.g. your 'Start' view controller and then chose *Editor* -> *Embed In...* -> *TabBarController* from the menu.

You should check out a tutorial on UITabBarController (e.g. [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-quick-tip-creating-a-uitabbar-application-with-storyboards--mobile-10449))

But in your case it seems to me, that you might simply want to add another `Show` segue from your 'Highscores' button to a third (currently not yet existing) 'Highscores' view controller.

Second question: **Why does the automatic back button not work?**

From what I see in your screenshot, there might be something wrong with how you added the navigation bar in your 'Het Spel' view controller (and perhaps in general).
Did you add the `UINavigationBar`, it's title and the rightBarButtonItem manually in Interface Builder?

I'd suggest to go back to square one and do this:

1) delete the navigation controller and all your current segues in IB. (Now there shouldn't be any navigation bar visible in both of your view controllers.)

2) select your 'Start' view controller in IB, and from the menu select *Editor* -> *Embed In...* -> *Navigation Controller*. (Now your 'Start' view controller should have a navigation bar, but 'Het Spel' should not.)

3) Ctrl-drag from the 'Speel het Spel!' button to the 'Het Spel' view controller and select the `Show` segue (`Push` segues are deprecated). (Now both of your view controllers should have navigation bars.)

4) In your code for both of your view controllers set the `title` property, and in 'Het Spel' also the rightBarButtonItem. E.g. in `viewDidLoad`:

```
// StartViewConroller
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Start"
}

// HetSpelViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Het Spel"
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Checken", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "checkenTapped")
}
```

Now the navigation bar in 'Het Spel' should automatically show a working back button named 'Start'.